# CKeditor Toolbar : AddButton (3.6)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, toolbar

I want to add a custom button to the toolbar.

Based on the information here : http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar I have this config.js :

```
 config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';

config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
[
    { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
    { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] },
    {
        name: 'forms', items: ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
          'HiddenField']
    },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
    {
        name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv',
        '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']
    },
    { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
    { name: 'insert', items: ['customImage', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe'] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
    { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About'] }
];


config.extraPlugins = 'customImage';
```

But the toolbar is not changed. It stays as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add some button to ckeditor, you have to do 3 steps:

1. Write your own plugin for the button some thing like this:

   (function () {
          // function when you click button
           var a = {
               exec: function (editor) {
                action when click button
                   }
           },
       b = 'videomanager';
           CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b, {
               init: function (editor) {
                   editor.addCommand(b, a);
                   editor.ui.addButton('videomanager', {
                       label: 'Video Manager',
                       icon: this.path + 'videomanager.png',
                       command: b
                   });
               }
           });
       })();
2. Register your plugin in ckeditor config.
3. Add to toolbar

Sorry, i can't format my code